# sequence of numbers using recursion

Tags: recursion, sequence

I want to compute sequence of numbers like this:

```
n*(n-1)+n*(n-1)*(n-2)+n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)+n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)*(n-4)+...+n(n-1)...(n-n)
```

For example `n=5` and sum equals `320`.

I have a function, which compute one element:

```
int fac(int n, int s)
{
    if (n > s)
        return n*fac(n - 1, s);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The last summand is always going to be zero (since you're multiplying by `n-n`).

Comment: Yes, it's better to write this sequence like you in answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomputing the factorial for each summand is quite wasteful. Instead, I'd suggest to use memoization. If you reorder

```
n*(n-1) + n*(n-1)*(n-2) + n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3) + n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)*...*1
```

you get

```
n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)*...*1 + n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3) + n*(n-1)*(n-2) + n*(n-1)
```

Notice how you start with the product of 1..n, then you add the product of 1..n divided by 1, then you add the product divided by 1*2 etc.

I think a much more efficient definition of your function is (in Python):

```
def f(n):
    p = product(range(1, n+1))
    sum_ = p
    for i in range(1, n-1):
        p /= i
        sum_ += p
    return sum_
```

A recursive version of this definition is:

```
def f(n):
    def go(sum_, i):
        if i >= n-1:
            return sum_
        return sum_ + go(sum_ / i, i+1)
    return go(product(range(1, n+1)), 1)
```

Last but not least, you can also define the function without any explicit recursion by using `reduce` to generate the list of summands (this is a more 'functional' -- as in functional programming -- style):

```
def f(n):
    summands, _ = reduce(lambda (lst, p), i: (lst + [p], p / i),
                         range(1, n),
                         ([], product(range(1, n+1))))
    return sum(summands)
```

This style is very concise in functional programming languages such as Haskell; Haskell has a function call `scanl` which simplifies generating the summands so that the definition is just:

```
f n = sum $ scanl (/) (product [1..n]) [1..(n-2)]
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's good solution. However it's not recursion solution.

Comment: @ElConrado: I added a recursive version now.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function fac(int n, int s)
{
    if (n >= s)
        return n * fac(n - 1, s);
    return 1;
}

int sum = 0;
int s = 4;
n = 5;
while(s > 0)
{
    sum += fac(n, s);
    s--;
}
print sum; //320
```

Loop-free version:

```
int fac(int n, int s)
{
    if (n >= s)
        return n * fac(n - 1, s);
    return 1;
}

int compute(int n, int s, int sum = 0)
{
    if(s > 0)
        return compute(n, s - 1, sum + fac(n, s));
    return sum;
}

print compute(5, 4); //320
```

Comment: It's quite good solution, but I am wondering is it possible to compute sum in one recursion? You use additional while loop to compute sum. I am looking for loop-free verssion :).

Comment: @ElConrado I edited the answer, although recusion uses a huge amount of resouces than with loop solution

Comment: Thanks, I think it's good answer however it's used two functions, but if there were connected it would be two calls.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ther is not mutch to write. I would suggest 2 methodes if you want to solve this recursiv. (Becaus of the recrusiv faculty the complexity is a mess and runtime will increase drasticaly with big numbers!)

```
  int func(int n){
     return func(n, 2);
   }

   int func(int n, int i){
        if (i < n){
           return n*(fac(n-1,n-i)+func(n, i + 1));      
        }else return 0;
    }


     int fac(int i,int a){
         if(i>a){
           return i*fac(i-1, a);
         }else return 1;
      }
```